# New to Angular - How to Remove a selected value from a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, jboss

I'm trying to learn a little basic AngularJS using this jboss quickstart: https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-wfk-quickstarts/tree/c488a5b/kitchensink-angularjs-bootstrap

Here's the service.js file:

```
angular.module('membersService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Members', function($resource){
  return $resource('rest/members/:memberId', {});
});
```

Pretty simple, right? And here's the relevant pieces of the controllers.js file:

```
$scope.register = function() {
  Members.save($scope.newMember, function(data) {}, function(result) {});
};

$scope.setSelected = function (member) {
    $scope.selectedMember = member;
    $scope.successMessages = [ $scope.selectedMember.name ];
}

$scope.unregister = function() {
    $scope.successMessages = [ 'Selected: ' + $scope.selectedMember.name ];
    Members.remove($scope.selectedMember, function(data) {}, function(result) {});
};
```

The "successMessages" are confirming that the value I'm selecting is getting captured. Here are the relavent POST/DELETE methods from the MemberResourceRESTService.java class:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createMember(Member member) {

        Response.ResponseBuilder builder = null;

        try {
            registration.register(member);
            builder = Response.ok();
        }  catch (Exception e) {}

        return builder.build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response removeMember(Member member) {

        Response.ResponseBuilder builder = null;

        try {
            registration.unregister(member);
            builder = Response.ok();
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        return builder.build();
    }
```

Basically the POST/Create Member piece is working, but the DELETE/Remove Member Rest method is getting a NULL Member passed in. I'm not sure why it's not making it over from the client, and what additional file/config I need to check. Apologies if this is a newbie question.

Comment: Use the browser's debugger and check if the Delete URL's api call is correct.

Comment: The Member isn't making it to the Delete URL api call. I'm not sure why it's not making it to the DELETE URL but it appears to be making it to the POST URL above.

Comment: Does the $scope.selectedMember have an 'id'? Because all you really need to remove the member is the id from the object. Basically check if this exists: $scope.selectedMember.id or in your case it might be $scope.selectedMember.memberId

Comment: It does have an id, and I've tried just passing that in. The problem is that no matter what I pass in to the "Members.remove()" method, it's not making its way to the server. I've even tried hardcoding an id i(Members.remove(0) for example) and the DELETE Rest method is getting a null passed in.

Comment: Your implementation is wrong. It should be something like this: Members.remove({ memberId: 1 }); So make sure that $scope.selectedMember has the mermberId as a property. Otherwise change 'rest/members/:memberId' to 'rest/members/:id'

Comment: Thanks so much! This was exactly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Hoyen's comments, I was able to perform two modification which fixed the issue:

1) In the controllers.js file, I had to modify the $scope.unregister function to look like this:

```
$scope.unregister = function() {
        Members.remove({ memberId : $scope.selectedMemberId });
    }
```

2) I had to modify my RestService to include Id PathParam:

```
@Path("/{memberId}")
@DELETE
public Response removeMember(@PathParam("memberId") long memberId) {

Response.ResponseBuilder builder = null;
try {
                registration.unregister(memberId);
                builder = Response.ok();
            } catch (Exception e) {}

            return builder.build();
}
```